# Calling delete or delete[] on NULL pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, null

Is it safe to always omit NULL pointer check before calling **delete** or **delete[]**, especially while writing cross-platform code sections?

I remember that few years ago (three or four) same code I wrote was working on MS Windows (compiled with MSVCv12 toolchain) but version compiled for Linux with g++ (unfortunately, I do not remember the g++ version) was throwing NULL pointer reference. I found information that it was probably a compiler error at that time.

I've found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329576/calling-delete-on-null-pointers-c03-vs-c11) but after reading it I'm still not quite sure if  it is safe and if so - from which version of the C++ standard?

Comment: what does it mean to "throw a NULL pointer reference" ?

Comment: "_I found information that it was probably a compiler error at that time._" How can the compiler check that the pointer being deleted is `nullptr`, and issue an error for it?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Pretty sure they meant "compiler bug".

Comment: That's right, I meant "compiler bug" instead of "compiler error". I'm sorry for my mistake.

Comment: [possible duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer)

Comment: use a smart pointer or vector and you no longer need to worry about the word delete at all

Comment: I recall a couple of VERY old C++ compilers (from 1992 or so) in which `delete (any_type *)NULL` or `delete [] (any_type *)NULL` would cause a runtime error.   But both those compilers (or their libraries) were fixed in a subsequent release, presumably due to bug reports.   I'm aware of no compiler more recent than 1995 which doesn't correctly deal with `delete NULL` - i.e. having no effect.   With modern compilers, a crash on any usage of operator `delete` - including `delete NULL` - is generally a symptom of some OTHER preceding code in the program exhibiting undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the standard, since C++98, guarantees that `delete` or `delete[]` on a nullpointer has no effect.

**C++98 §5.3.5/2**

> **”** In either alternative, if the value of the operand of `delete` is the null pointer the operation has no effect.

This was so also before the first standard, when the language was defined by the Annotated Reference Manual.

---

Regarding

> **”** version compiled for Linux with g++ (unfortunately, I do not remember the g++ version) was throwing NULL pointer reference

That's impossible to discuss without a concrete and preferably complete example that reproduces the behavior. It had nothing to do with deleting a nullpointer.

Comment: there is one little detail abou C++11 and later: it is unspecified if deallocation function is called or not if pointer is null, so it would be unsafe if deallocation function is re-implemented by user in way it may cause fault or UB if pointer is nullptr. But it is case of crafting a rake and stepping on it thereafter

Comment: @Swift -- `operator delete` and `operator delete[]` are required to handle null pointers sensibly. "Requires: [the pointer argument] shall be a null pointer or its value shall be a value returned by an earlier call to [operator new]". [new.delete.single], repeated in [new.delete.array]. If you replace operator delete you are on notice that your version can be called with a null pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know that, but some don't. There were questions about that on SO. I just noted that as a source of insecure behaviour in addition to quite fine and upvoted answer. The thing is that when we write delete, it's delete expression which would rely on operator delete supplied by user if one present. Just like with new-expression compiler there acts as mediator. Some imagine that compiler out to fix that, while ISO leaves that undefined