# Destructor always hitting Null

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I´m currently playing around with linked lists today.
I got everything to work just fine though I always seem to run into the same Problem,the destructor no matter what, it seems to always run into a NULL object when accessing the destructor in any form, throwing an "access rights violation Error"

> "this->**next**" was "0xDDDDDDDD".

```
struct Liste {
Liste *next;
int content;
Liste() {
    content = 0;
    next = nullptr;
};
~Liste() {
    if (next == nullptr) {
        return;
    }else if (next->next == nullptr){
        delete next;
        return;
    }else {
        next->~Liste();
    }
};
};
```

I´m quite unsure and curious about what could be the source for this Error.
It always occurs no matter the way i try to use delete on it.
The solutions i found so far were:
-simply call delete on the first element and it calls the destructor of the others
-try to check if next in line IS Null but it doesn´t seem to filter it out at all
-try to go through it iteratively but that too did run into ground zero
-try to implement it in a class which did work just as fine as this did, up to the point i had to implement a deletion which ran into the exact same Error

Id be happy to receive some tips on how to fix/avoid this since not deleting it at all cant be a good idea, and i'm not sure at all what exactly went  wrong in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: According to [Wikipedia's great list of magic debug codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values), 0xDDDDDDDD suggests access of memory that has already been freed. Know ye [The Rule of Three!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Unrelated `next->~Liste();` is a bad idea. You almost never want to manually call a destructor (Notable exceptions are non-POD union members and objects constructed with placement new). Use `delete next;` instead.

Comment: You have a memory leak in your program due to manually calling destructor, but that unlikely be the roor cause of that memory access. we cannot help you without [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your destructor just needs to do:

```
~Liste() {
    delete next;
}
```

If `next` is not `null`, then `delete next;` will call the destructor of the next element, which in turn will call the destructor of the next element, and so on. If `next` is `null` then `delete next;` will not do anything, which is fine.

Comment: This is a recipe for overflowing your stack. You recurse up to a depth of `n`

Comment: @Justin Yes, you're right about that, I was thinking of a "programming practice" solution but in a real use case an iterative solution would be better, feel free to post one and I'll upvote that.

Comment: And how does this explain what is wrong with and point to the error in the OP's code?

Comment: Calling `delete` on null pointers is not what it used to be. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329576/calling-delete-on-null-pointers-c03-vs-c11.

Comment: @Justin I don't think a stack overflow should be a concern in simple code like this. At worst, every stack frame need only hold a single `this` pointer and you'd need an enormous list to cause problems. This destructor could also easily be optimized into a loop for being essentially tail-recursive.

Comment: @alterigel Perhaps, but also consider that running in debug with no optimizations on is a very common occurrence. As a rule of thumb, only recurse if you can keep the stack growth as `O(log n)`

Comment: I wish C++ had tail recursion optimization.  :-(

Comment: This is not an answer for the question, though that destructor is written badly, it is unlikely it is the reason for that memory access

Comment: @Eljay I'm waiting for the telepathic compiler. One that generates code that does what you want, not what you told it to.

Answer (score 1):

Without a stack overflow compared to the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846758/1731200):

```
~Liste() {
     Liste* temp = nullptr;
     while (next) {
         temp       = next->next;
         next->next = nullptr;
         delete next;
         next       = temp;
     }
 }
```

With regard to the given code:

```
~Liste() {
    if (next == nullptr) {
        return;
    } else if (next->next == nullptr){
        delete next;
        return;
    } else {
        next->~Liste(); // *next is destructed, but next is not deallocated!
    }
};
```

Though, the given code (including the destructor) is probably not the reason for the bad memory access as already mentioned by **Slava**.

Comment: I think proper solution is to have separate classes for node and list itself, and implement this logic in list's destructor. Here list has link to another list, which is actually a node.

Comment: @Slava indeed; I once wrote a [doubly linked list](https://github.com/matt77hias/cpp-samples/blob/master/Samples/doubly_linked_list/code.hpp) which uses a separate class to represent the links.

Comment: I think just about everybody wrote that doubly linked list program at one point or another. God it must get boring to mark this stuff after a while.