# How to fix "not all control paths return a value" in lambda expression

Tags: c++

I have some code with lambda expression and my problem is that I would like to return something only if "if" isn't nullptr. Other way I don't want to return anything. Is there a return that can be used in this code? Or maybe another way to not getting warning?

```
auto iter = std::stable_partition(object1->vector_.begin(), object1->vector_.end(), [](Class* x)  
{
    if (x->object2_ != nullptr)
    {

        return !x->object2->parameter_;
    }

});
```

It's working good, but this warning is annoying and I know that I should do something with this.

Comment: What should happen if `x->object2_ == nullptr`?  Answer that and you'll know what to do.

Comment: nothing should happen I think...

Comment: return false is like nothing happened?

Comment: A function always needs to return something if it has a return type that is not `void`.  So if `x->object2_ == nullptr` then you still need to return something.

Comment: I know, but what?

Comment: Is it possible that `x->object2_`  is null in a well-formed program in your domain? If not, throw an exception.

Comment: It is possible and it is very common, I need to nothing happen if "if" is false.

Comment: The function needs to return true for elements that should come first.  That means it should return ____ for elements that come last.

Comment: You could have `throw "Oops";` at the end.

Comment: @VidelIchinose You are partitioning your container. On what side of the partition do you want objects that have `x->object2_ == nullptr`?

Comment: @VidelIchinose *"I need nothing to happen"* Your function *already* does nothing, it just *checks* something. It passes judgement on various instances without changing anything. It's `stable_partition` that does something.

Answer (score 3):

The intent of [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) is:

> Reorders the elements in the range [first, last) in such a way that all elements for which the predicate p returns true precede the elements for which predicate p returns false. Relative order of the elements is preserved.

When you use

```
return !x->object2->parameter_;
```

you want to put all the elements for which `!x->object2->parameter_` is true to the left and all the elements for which `!x->object2->parameter_` is false to the right.

Judging by that, I would say if `x->object2_` is a `nullptr`, you should put them to the right. Hence, the default `return` needs to be

```
return false;
```

Hence,

```
auto iter = std::stable_partition(object1->vector_.begin(),
                                  object1->vector_.end(),
                                  [](Class* x) -> bool
{
    if (x->object2_ != nullptr)
    {
        return !x->object2->parameter_;
    }

    return false;
});
```

You can combine the body of the function to one line as:

```
auto iter = std::stable_partition(object1->vector_.begin(),
                                  object1->vector_.end(),
                                  [](Class* x) -> bool
{
    return (x->object2_ != nullptr) && (!x->object2->parameter_);
});
```

Comment: @VidelIchinose, that is true. You'll have to: 1) Make sure that there is no such object in the vector, or 2) Add code to deal with them.

Comment: This is the comment I deleted, sorry. 

Ok, I see, but after that, I have std::for_each(iter, object1->vector_.end(), [](Class *x) {delete x->object2; }); So when I'm using return false; I have null object2s... I think

Comment: Is a deleting null object very bad? Because actually it is working and there is no warning, except some redundancy

Comment: @VidelIchinose when you say *deleting null object*, do you mean the C++ statement `delete obj;`?

Comment: yes, exactly. Because if obj=nullptr and then we do delete obj; nothing happen, am I right?

Comment: @VidelIchinose, yes you may. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329576/calling-delete-on-null-pointers-c03-vs-c11.

Comment: @VidelIchinose But do you want to delete all `object2_`'s or only those with no `parameter_`? In the latter case you could use `iter` instead of `end()` in your `for_each`.